# Unable to run Spring Mvc tutorial example in a tomcat Docker

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, docker

Going through the [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service), I've downloaded [the complete code](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/archive/master.zip). And made the following change to the pom.xml file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Running `mvn package` I created the `gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war` file.

Then I downloaded the Tomcat docker `tomcat:8.0` and enabled the `manager-gui` for the tomcat user so I can use the web page manager. Logging into the web interface, I deployed the generated .war package file into the Tomcat server. Once started, I navigated to `http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting` and faced:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting

type Status report

message /gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
```

Enabling the tomcat's log, it doesn't output any error, just:

```
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.746 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-61] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [uriBC] has value [/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting]
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.746 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-61] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.747 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-61] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [enc] has value [utf-8]
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.747 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-61] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   No applicable constraints defined
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.764 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [uriBC] has value [/favicon.ico]
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.765 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
09-Mar-2016 19:04:31.765 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [enc] has value [utf-8]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you export the code in your workspace ?

Comment: I didn't use any IDE, I just used `mvn package` in command line. Then uploaded the war file through the Tomcat's web page.